# MySQL Dump Limit? MySQL overall database size limit?

Tags: limit, mysql, loss

Client just had ~1000 rows of data (most recent, of course), just go missing in one of their tables. Doing some forensics, I found that the "last_updated_date" in all of their other rows of said table was also set to roughly the same time as the deletion occurred. This is not one of their larger tables.

Some other oddities are that the mysqldumps for the last week are all *exact* same size -- 10375605093 Bytes. Previous dumps grew by about .5GB each. MySQL Dump command is standard:

```
/path/to/mysqldump -S /path/to/mysqld2.sock --lock-all-tables -u username -ppassword database > /path-to-backup/$(date +%Y%m%d)_live_data.mysqldump
```

df -h on the box shows plenty of space (at least 50%) in every directory.

The data loss combined with the fact that their dumps are not increasing in size has me worried that somehow we're hitting some hardcoded limit in MySQL and (God I hope I'm wrong), data is getting corrupted. Anyone ever heard of anything like this? How can we explain the mysqldump sizes?

Answer (score 3):

50% free space doesn't mean much if you're doing multiple multi-gig dumps and run out of space halfway. Unless you're storing binary data in your dumps, they are quite compressible, so I'd suggest piping mysqldump's output through gzip before outputting to a file:

```
mysqldump .... | gzip -9 > /path_to_backup/....
```

MySQL itself doesn't have any arbitrary limits that say "no more after X gigs", but there are limits imposed by the platform it's running on, [detailed here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html).

Comment: It's absolutely not running out of disk space... each dump is ~10GB and the disk has 366GB Avail

Comment: You may want to redirect stderr out to another file to capture any error output myssqldump's producing. `msyqldump ... > dump.sql 2> dump.err` and see what shows up there. For instance, if there's a blob in the DB that exceeds max_allowed_packet, then the dump will abort at that point.

Comment: running from command line (with our without dumping stderr) still produces no output... it just looks like it ran perfect (but file is done at 10375605093). du -k on the data dir shows it at about 1.45 GB now (and growing). I'm really beyond stumped. tail -1 on the dumpfile shows expected "Dump completed on 2011-08-05 17:33:29"...

Comment: Figured it out (sortof). Seems that the developer who set this up had a 2nd database running + listening on that /path/to/mysqld2.sock socket. Once we realized that the main server was running on a different socket, just taking the "-S" out and specifying the new creds worked. Still digging, but it looks like the 2nd database was perhaps a slave which stopped (thus the sizes of dumps stopped incrementing). Thanks for all the pointers, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There is no hardcoded limit to the amount of data MySQL can handle.

Comment: digging deeper... it's not a "max_allowed_packet" issue (alahttp://rackerhacker.com/2007/10/11/mysqldump-got-packet-bigger-than-max_allowed_packet-bytes/), and file system is Linux / ext4... max file size is 16TB (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4). Still completely clueless here...