# Mysqldump is not extracting all data

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I have an aurora MySQL table with about 4.5 billion records. I am trying to migrate it to another environment. I am trying to dump it using MySQL dump functionality and then restore it from the dump file. But it seems to dump the data only partially. about 420k records. Any reason why this is happening. 
I searched the internet high and low. But nobody seems to have faced this issue.

Any suggestion on how to migrate thi?

Comment: This might be a good option for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962349/mysql-dump-limit-mysql-overall-database-size-limit

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably hitting a file or memory limit size somewhere. I would try and find a sensible way to split the dumps up into separate files.

Comment: Is there a way i can split the single table into multiple dump files?